# Decode and send a VGA video stream using AVR

Tags: microcontroller, avr

I'm planning to use a AVR microcontroller, (ATMEGA32) to read a vga video signal, then send this signal to pc using usb. Is it possible to decode and send VGA signal with AVR ? My question is, Is the processing capability of avr is enough to decode VGA signal real time ?

Comment: See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Graphics_Array - note particularly the master clock's frequency - ~25 or ~28 Mhz. The 16MHz clock of a AtMega32 is ever going to be fast enough - nor do I know how to work out what will be fast enough. I'd consider going with an FPGA. You can get them for about $13 on Ebay. A popular one is often used as a USB sampling digital oscilloscope, I forget the number of the chip. It may/may not be suitable.

Comment: it is possible however with heavily reduced resolution in x, for example 640x480 60Hz signal has 25.175MHz dot clock if you can read at least at 8 MHz (which I doubt you can directly with GPIO however busses like EBI are usable for this), by oversampling you can read the missing pixels by reading sligthly dellayed at cost of lower framerate... you can also ignore ADC (AVR ADC are too slow) and use just `H/L` states (limiting to 8 colors)... I am genearting VGA signal with AVR32 using EBI which is more or less the same as reading ... If you use DMA you can achieve even better performance

Comment: you main problem will be memory as storing the frame will use a lot of memory most MCUs dont have so you might consider using external SDRAM ... btw see this [my old version of VGA generator on AVR32](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59893678/2521214) right now I am upgrading that to something less CPU intense, btw memory is also my limit for resolution during VGA signal generation.

Comment: @Spektre thanks for the comments, but as you can see it was 8 years ago. I ended up not doing the project.

Writing VGA might be easier in that sense, I did produce an good looking vga signal using raspberry pi (different project). It outputs the colors as digital 8 bit signals, converting it to analog vga signal was easy with resistive ladders. 

You might also want to look at this https://github.com/bitluni/ESP32Lib

Answer (score 1):

no it is too slow. you need some really fast ADC to read the video signals and some µC that supports USB 2.0 and a µC with some more processing power.